# How do I parse XML with german umlauts in ! names?

Tags: java, xml, diacritics, tagname

I try to parse XML in java by

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Everything seems to be ok, also

```
<data>äöü</data>
```

is parsed correctly (esp. concerning the german umlauts).

But when I try to parse

```
<däta>xxx</däta>
```

the parser throws an exception, names with umlauts in it seem to not work:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WFä at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.NodeImpl.setName(NodeImpl.java:286) at
org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.AttrImpl.<init>(AttrImpl.java:55) at 
org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.createAttribute(DocumentImpl.java:324) at 
org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.jav‌​a:314) at 
org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.jav‌​a:321) at 
org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.jav‌​a:128)
```

Comment: I am not even sure that such tag names are legal; are they?

Comment: What exception are you receiving, and is the data *actually* in UTF-8? Have you tried just parsing the input stream directly instead? What does the XML declaration look like?

Comment: @fge: Such tagnames ARE legal. I just found out, that e.g.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, `db.parse` doesn't throw any exception and `doc.getFirstChild()` returns `däta` Node and when I call `getTextContent()` on it I get `xxx`. Can you post entire stacktrace of exception you are getting?

Comment: Can you try to create a new project with just the XML parsing code? See if it stills throws an exception. To me everything works fine

Comment: What exception does the parser throw?

Comment: @Pshemo: it happens for me on android only --- @fge: `ex.toString() + " :: " + ex.getMessage()` gives `org.w3c.dom.DOMException: däta :: däta`

Comment: The most important thing about an exception is its stacktrace. You should share that instead, and also the exact Java platform/version. This may well end up as an implementation bug. BTW `DOMException` is not a parser error, it signals DOM API usage error.

Comment: Stacktrace is `org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WFä
 at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.NodeImpl.setName(NodeImpl.java:286)
 at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.AttrImpl.<init>(AttrImpl.java:55)
 at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.createAttribute(DocumentImpl.java:324)
 at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:314)
 at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:321)
 at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:128)...`

Comment: (in my implementation I used an umlauted attribute name, that's why it appears in `createAttribute`

Comment: It's Android 4.4.2 - I don't know the java version

Comment: You *can* edit your own question :) Anyway, Apache Harmony apparently thinks that an XML identifier must be strict ASCII. It's clear from the source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robovm/robovm-rt/0.0.14/org/apache/harmony/xml/dom/DocumentImpl.java#DocumentImpl.isXMLIdentifierPart%28char%29

Comment: ouch !!! After reviewing the harmony code, I have to state, that they implemented wrong (against standard, using ascii only instead of "unicode letter characters"). So it's in fact an implementation error, and we have to use another parser :(  --- Thanks to all.

Comment: Consider filing a bug on your parsers bug tracker.

Answer (score 3):

Acccording to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar) of tag names, valid characters are:

```
":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
| "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

The char 'ä' is 0x00E4 and is therefore in the `[#xD8-#xF6]` block and is valid in tag names. Throw away your XML parser ;-)